# Parallel testing with cucumber, selenium and junit 5

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, cucumber

My goal is to run features in parralel, but scenarios in order they were written.

I faced the situation where only adding this annotation to RunnerTest class allow to run tests in parallel

```
@ConfigurationParameters({
        @ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "web.selenium.steps, web.selenium.testRunner"),
        @ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty, html:target/report.html, io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm"),
        @ConfigurationParameter(key = PARALLEL_EXECUTION_ENABLED_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "true"),
```

But main problem that after i run tests, they run in wrong order of scenarios. How can i specify order of scenarios?

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#executing-features-in-parallel

Comment: @M.P. Korstanje Thanks, that worked! But after some manipulations with correct version of cucumber-junit-platform-engine dependency. My version of it was too old for needed constant and newest version has some problems with running tests. But it is working on 7.9.0 version of dependency

Comment: What breaks on later versions?

Comment: Internal Error occurred. org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-platform-suite' failed to discover tests

Comment: If you can reproduce that with the https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton project, then please file a bug report. If you can not reproduce it, it might be that your (transitive) dependencies are conflicting. Analyse with `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`.

Comment: All dependency problems were fixed with updating all pom dependencies to newest ones